# TypeError: Cannot set property 'lint' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vagrant, homestead, shopware, shopware6

I am currently in the process of teaching myself Shopware 6 (current master branch) and am trying to do this in combination with VueJS and Shopware PWA. I have Shopware PWA installed with

```
git clone https://github.com/elkmod/SwagShopwarePwa.git custom/plugins/SwagShopwarePwa
```

and activated. Now I try to configure the plugin with `shopware-pwa` but the console shows me this error:

```
✔ Shopware instance address: · http://my.domain.com
✔ Shopware instance access token: · MYTOKEN
✔ Which version you'd like to use: · canary (current master branch)
✔ Preparing Nuxt project
⠧ Updating configuration for option: canary (current master branch)/usr/lib/node_modules/@shopware-pwa/cli/node_modules/gluegun/build/index.js:13
    throw up;
    ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'lint' of undefined
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/@shopware-pwa/cli/build/extensions/nuxt-extension.js:163:49
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/@shopware-pwa/cli/node_modules/gluegun/build/toolbox/patching-tools.js:91:39)
    at step (/usr/lib/node_modules/@shopware-pwa/cli/node_modules/gluegun/build/toolbox/patching-tools.js:33:23)
    at Object.next (/usr/lib/node_modules/@shopware-pwa/cli/node_modules/gluegun/build/toolbox/patching-tools.js:14:53)
    at fulfilled (/usr/lib/node_modules/@shopware-pwa/cli/node_modules/gluegun/build/toolbox/patching-tools.js:5:58)
```

Thanks for your comming help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the same problem and created an issue on Github. Feel free to subscribe to it: https://github.com/DivanteLtd/shopware-pwa/issues/1164

Comment: I solved the problem with an Shopware 6 engineer. I'll write the solution in your GitHub issue :)